Identify history of rock animated film
I'm trying to remember the name of an animated film, starred by a female character, who lives through the history of rock. The film contains dozens of song from different decades.
The character has some sort of magical powers thanks to her earrings, and she loses one of them, or both (I do not remember exactly). She has a boyfriend in each decade and at the end, if I remember correctly, she finds all of them combined in one man.

This sounds a lot like Jem (and the Holograms), an animated TV show about a rock singer who wears hi-tech earrings. There are plenty of weird episodes, including one where she travels back in time and meets famous musicians ("Journey Through Time"). The show is about to be remade as a live-action film (but the less said about that, the better).

@Walt Thanks, but it is not that one. I'm looking for an animation film, not a series.

OK, thanks. I know what you're looking for. I'll put it up. BTW, please try to supply as many basic details as possible (year, country\language etc). They help narrow things down.

You're looking for Hanna-Barbera's Rock Odyssey from 1987. From Wikipedia:

The story of a mysterious woman named Laura, who embarks on a journey to find her true love. The movie's soundtrack is set to four decades of classic rock. Scatman Crothers provides the voice of a living jukebox who narrates the story.

Here are some clips with the talking jukebox:




Very probably this is it. Just let me check.

Yes, this is it. Thanks. Accepted.
